# can't change yii CCheckboxColumn value

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I made a small app: there is a lost of users , I check those who I want , click a button and a certain message is being sent to their emails.

I'm using yii's checkbox column and ajax in order to send the users' emails to the action in the controller.

Now, in order to be able to debug this app , I set the destination address to mine , and the users' emails in the message variable.

The app works! BUT , I get the users' ids instead of their emails.
Checkbox column sends the model's id by default , but one can change it with 'name' or 'value' , HOWERVER , for some reason both those lines simply doesn't work.

I'm sitting on this for four days , I wrote another ajax , but I'm still gettin the id.

I'd be vey gladful if anyone can help me. Here's the code:

The gridview:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'test-person-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'email',
    array(         
            'id'=>'col',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows'=>'2',
            'value'=>'$data->email',
        ),


    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
```

)); ?>

The ajax:

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('send','
$("#sender").click(function(){
        var checked=$("#test-person-grid").yiiGridView("getChecked","col");
        var count=checked.length;
        if(count>0 && confirm(" do you want to send "+count+" message? "))
        {
                $.ajax({
                        data:{checked:checked},
                        url:"'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('testPerson/sender')).'",
                        success:function(data){$("#test-person-grid").yiiGridView("update",{});},              
                });
        }
        });
');
?>
```

The controller action:

```
public function actionSender()
{
     if(Yii::app()->request->getIsAjaxRequest())
    { 
            $checkedMails=$_GET['checked'];
            foreach($checkedMails as $message)
            {
                mail('mark@gmail.com', 'Test mail', $message);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Probably sloppy, but could you not do a foreach loop to check your user id and create a new array of emails before you do the `foreach($checkedMails as $message)`. Also could possibly show the `$checkedMails` array.

Comment: This sounds like a solution, but I ran into 3 problems: 1)The whole array is not send, unlesss I separate it with "foreach" 2) I found how to create an array in yii , but not how to take the attributes from the $id in another aray (tried SQL query - didn't work eather)  3) I tried to leave the foreach and use the "get attributes" function , didn't worked eather :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! Finally it works.
I used only one foreach , and under it I used the findByPk like this:

```
 $checkedIds=$_GET['checked'];
            foreach($checkedIds as $id)
            {
                $message=TestPerson::model()->findByPk($id)->email;     
                mail('mark@gmail.com', 'Test mail', $message);
            }
```

Cheers,
Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You have the userID so I would do a findByPK on in the controller.

This question on the YII forum is the same and the answer given by the staff is the same. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/48235-fnyiigridviewgetchecked-returns-empty-values/